# How to use files from my computer with a Docker?

Tags: docker, file, local

I am trying to run this command: 
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/input shamelesscookie/vmaf yuv420p 1920 1080 /input/file1.yuv /input/file2.yuv --out-fmt json

But I don't understand how to use files that are stored on my computer for: 
- /input/file1.yuv
- /input/file2.yuv

Comment: Which OS do you use? If Windows, you need to enable a particular directory to be shared. Check docs: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives